# What is the size of the marked area (calculate without computer)?

Tags: real-analysis, recreational-mathematics

Recently I scribbled a representation of squares which should challenge the imagination of the infiniteness of the sum $$s_1=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...$$ and of the finiteness of the sum $$s_2=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...$$
The following picture puts together

- the infinite length of a line constructed of the partial series of $s_1$ (using the length unit "cm" for example) and
- the finite area constructed of the partial series of $s_2$ (in "cm²") which is enclosed by a border of infinite length:

[image: picture1]

Ok, I mean this picture gives a nice composition *(of a finite area limited by an infinite line)* for some interesting amateur.

After that, I thought: what if I smooth that figure by connecting the edges of the squares with straight lines? What is the size of the newly introduced area (yellow)? Is a purely geometrical solution possible?

[image: picture2]

***Challenge1:*** find a formula for the yellow area without the use of a computer. I think I needed about an hour to find the (very nice) solution with pen&paper (feeling a bit rusty needing such a long time... ).

***Challenge2:*** If the edges are connected with a smooth interpolating ***curve*** instead of straight pieces - what could be a formula with the target of simpleness and of straightness of the curve? (If I got the terminology correct, the ideal were a "absolute monotonous" function, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).)
As a "poor man's approach" I thought one might rotate the picture by 45 deg first towards the x-axis. Then the new area could be expressed by the integral for the curve's formula. Give such an integral and the area.

My first approach was to "generalize" the formula for polynomial interpolation using the heights of the upper edges *(when the diagonal of the figure is rotated to the x-axis)* towards an infinite number of interpolation-points; one problem with this is that the x-coordinates of the interpolation-points are not equidistant. (I've no solution so far, possibly one can employ the  $\psi()$-function as interpolation of the harmonic numbers.)

Comment: This is not the place for stating questions and expecting people to solve them. People will want to see your current thoughts about the problem and some attempt at solving it yourself. You almost certainly won't get any answers to your first 'challenge' as you say you already know the answer. In this case, you could either state your answer and ask if it is correct/optimal, or simply delete the challenge and add some context around your second 'challenge' instead. Your first challenge *may* be on topic at [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) but read their criteria first

Comment: @lioness99a - thanks for your comment. I had the impression, that the "recreational mathematics" has some flair for toy-challenges on amateur-level. I'll see what's wrong with it.

Comment: You can always ask on [Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) for other opinions on whether your question fits the tag

Comment: This is a nice problem, for sure ! I hope and wish that you will answer your question. Cheers :-)

Comment: Concerning the appropriateness of this question for MSE. From the tags-descriptions. `recreational` - *Mathematics done just for fun, often disjoint from typical school mathematics curriculum. Also see the [puzzle] and [contest-math] tags.*   `puzzle` - *For questions about the mathematical principles behind puzzle, games, riddles, or their possible solutions. Questions that are not strictly mathematical in nature should be asked on Puzzling Stack Exchange.* I think, the question is appropriate here.

Comment: Your challenge 1 is straightforward, however challenge 2 seems quite vaguely stated.  With a target like “simpleness”, its hard to imagine what you want, when obviously segment wise linear curve appears simplest for me.  Did you intend smooth or $C^1$ curves for e.g.?

Comment: @Macavity - yes, "smooth" is perhaps a good choice for that what I mean. 1) For instance a hyperbel, if that could match *all* (upper) edges when the picture is rotated such that the diagonal is on the x-axis. 2) for the unrotated plot I've considered the psi()-function as interpolation of the harmonic numbers (which occur in the y-axis, but the x-coordinates are not evenly spaced, so I didn't see a way how to applicate it correctly.

Comment: Part 1 results in the classic telescoping sum. It would be nice if this had a geometric interpretation in the figure, but I don't see it.

Comment: @Macavity - I'm toying around with the psi()-function as implemented in Pari/GP for the interpolation of the set of upper edges as seen in the first picture. Here is my function-definition, which unfortunately lacks a true functional inverse of the psi(): `f(z)=psi(2+solve(x=0,10,psi(1+x)+Euler-z))+Euler`   and then I calculate the definite integrals numerically for instance from $0$ to $1$ by `intnum(t=1e-10,1,f(t))` where I cannot insert $0$ as the lower border of the integral. But somehow a smoother function would be nice...

Comment: @Macavity - just a small addition. Pari/GP is nice enough to give an approximation for the integral `intnum(t=1e-20,50,f(t)-t  )` (where the `solve` part has now an upper bound of *1e50*) as about $\small 1.30075505601$

Comment: Given the countably infinite points, there would be infinite number of curves which pass through them, even to any desired degree of smoothness. There may not be closed form expressions for these, but i fail to see how we can seek any unique solution for the given conditions.

Comment: @Macavity - "absolute monotonuous": a better term for the "ideal" of an interpolation (from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) ?

Comment: Here is a wikipedia link for the second challenge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Harmonic_numbers_for_real_and_complex_values . We take $t ↦ (H_{t+1}, H_{t+2})$. EDIT: Hm, it doesn't work for the starting points.

Comment: @Idéophage - ah, very nice! I'll see how I can use this. The reference to the "digamma()" is what I know as "psi()" (by Pari/GP-training...) . The integral-formula is new to me, I'll see what I can take from it! I know also the series expression for the digamma/psi ; the problem which occurs here is, that the x-coordinates are not on equidistant points, so we need also the functional inverse of the digamma/psi() ...

Comment: The lower corner points have coordinates $(H_n,H_{n-1})$, which can be approximated by $(\log(n)+\gamma,\log(n-1)+\gamma)$, corresponding to the curve $y=\log(e^x-e^\gamma)$ - so-called SoftMinus.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had also another, even better, solution for challenge1 than the following which I show below.
Here is the version using the telescoping sum.

---

Let's denote the yellow triangular pieces as $t_k$ beginning from the left, primarily looking above the main diagonal. We see, that each $t_k$ comes in two exemplars (above and below the diagonal) which can be combined to a rectangle of the size $A_k$. The area of the two $t_k$ is 
$$ A_k = \frac1{k(k+1)}$$
Then the partial series for the sequences of the yellow pieces (taken as pairs of same size) is
 $$\sum_{k=1}^n A_k = \frac12 + \frac16+\frac1{12}+ \cdots + \frac1{n(n+1)}$$

If we look at each term separately it can be decomposed in a difference of reciprocals:
 $$S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n A_k = (1-\frac12) + (\frac12-\frac13)+(\frac13-\frac14)+ \cdots + (\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n)+(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1})$$
which gives by cancelletaion of the intermediate terms:
$$ S(n) = 1 - \frac1{n+1}$$ 
giving in the limit the area
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} S(n) \text{ cm}^2  = 1 \text{ cm}^2 $$

---

The process from $S(n) $ to $S(n+1)$ can be pictured as follows:

[image: picture1]
Here the yellow pieces are sequentially the pieces $t_k$ producing the partial sums
$$S(n)= A_1+A_2+...+A_n = 1 - \frac1{n+1} $$
by considering subsequently the residual areas. The area of the subsequent grey areas obviously go to zero.

Remark: I think there are better graphic representations, but to start I give the first  one coming to mind.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, a smooth curve through the square corners are obtained via the digamma function in parametric form, as 
$$(\gamma+\psi_0(t),\gamma+\psi_0(t+1))$$ and

$$(\gamma+\psi_0(t+1),\gamma+\psi_0(t)).$$

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility to express things. Is it possible to use this moreover to express the problem by something like $f(x)= g( g^{o-1}(x)-1)$ ? The Hurwitz-zeta in this composition should not allow an inverse?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: yes, the function is invertible. But I doubt that the inverse even has a name. Calculating the area (which can be done using the parametric equations) is quite challenging.

Comment: Well, I'll see perhaps I can find something more about this. Just to answer the reservations by @macavity: is there some property which makes this solution "unique" (and "best suited" over other solutions, for example composition with periodic secondary functions)?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: I have rewritten with digamma. This solution has the advantage of being the analytical continuation of the Harmonic numbers.

Comment: Yves - yes, in Pari/GP they call it "psi()". I've implemented a "fake"-inverse of it using the `solve()`-procedure. This gives the features that I've described in my comments to user Macavity, even that estimate for a integral from zero to large $x$ ( infinity?). If this can be made more elegant I'd like it very much!

Comment: Hallo Yves, I've written my work on challenge2 in the afternoon/evening as a new answer, see there. It attempts to rewrite the parametrical solution as a functional one. (Don't know whether this is optimal, though)

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt to challenge2.

This is the plot of the problem, where the upper and lower edges are connected by piecewise linear lines:
[image: picture1]

The better interpolation idea is, that the (somehow) "natural" interpolation of the harmonic numbers is the "digamma()" or "psi()"-function.
In Pari/GP we can implement the function "harmonic number" $h(x)$ as
$$ h(x) = \text{psi}(1+x)+\text{Euler} $$ to get for instance
$$ h(2) = 1.5 = 1+1/2 $$
I don't know any function being the functional inverse of $h(x)$ so I implement it using the `solve()` procedure to fake it at least for a certain domain.
$$ h^{o-1}(z) = \text{solve}(x=10^{-20},10^{50},h(x)-z) $$
Then I define
$$ f^+(x)= h(h^{o-1}(x)+1) \qquad \text{for the upper edges} \\ 
f^-(x)= h(h^{o-1}(x)-1) \qquad \text{for the lower edges} $$
With this we can plot the smooth interpolation $f(x)=f^+(x)$ based on the digamma()/psi()-function:
[image: picture2]

(I show here only a detail because the plot overlays the straight lines and the interpolation by $f(x)$ to partial invisibility)

With this Pari/GP can even approximate the area between the upper interpolation and the main diagonal by the numerical computation of the integral as
$$ B = \int_{10^{-20}}^{50} f(t)-t \quad dt \approx  1.30075505601 $$
and the size of the yellow area (when its borders are interpolated by $f(x)$) is about
$$ 2 B - \zeta(2) \approx  0.956576045162 = 1 - 0.0434239548377 $$
which is about $0.0434239548377$ less than the value $1$ for the piecewise linear bordered yellow area.

Whether this is the best, or at least most meaningful, solution I don't know. Especially I'd like to have a more common expression for $f(x)$ or at least a powerseries....